# Boundary value problem domain, norm?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces

I'm starting some research on a boundary value problem for a memoire for the 2nd semester of a masters, and my mentoring professor asked me to find the answer to the following question:

For $u \in H^{1,0}(Ω)$ (i.e. u and ∂u are in $L^2$, while $u=0$ on the boundary ∂Ω), $Ω\subset R^2$ and bounded, the boundary of Ω, ∂Ω, piecewise $C^1$, is there a geometric condition on Ω so that the function $u \to \| \,|\nabla u| \,\|_{L^2}$ is a norm? (Without using the Poincaré inequality).

I'm not supposed to figure this out alone, supposedly it's in a book I have as a reference (Introduction à l'analyse numérique des équations aux dérivées partielles, Raviart-Thomas), but I can't seem to find anything helpful. I tried showing that this is a norm, and the problem seems to be that the "norm" being 0 only implies that $|\nabla u|=0$, which doesn't necessarily give $u=0$. Any ideas? I'm not really sure how a geometric condition on Ω could help with that problem.

P.S. Sorry I don't know how to make math symbols in here, and copy-pasting from elsewhere doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by module? BTW: for the math take a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), or if you want to copy/paste from another post, click on 'edit' and then copy from the source.

Comment: The gradient is a vector, so to take the $L^2$ norm of it, we need to take the module (this is a non-translation from French, maybe we'd call it the length in English), denoted by the absolute value sign, of it in order to integrate it.

Comment: Hmm, but the Poincare inequality guarantees that this is a norm if you have $u=0$ on the boundary and $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz domain. So, I can't see any additional geometric condition that needs to hold for $\Omega$ here.

Comment: If the gradient is 0, then $u$ is a constant function. There is only one function satisfying that with your boundary conditions.

Comment: If $u=0$, isn't it also a possibility that the sum of the partial derivatives are 0? 
Perhaps Ω being a Lipschitz domain is the extra condition? If having the boundary piecewise $C^1$ doesn't guarantee that, I'm not sure if that is sufficiently regular.

Comment: Sorry, I mean if $|\nabla u|=0$ ^^